# Binding vs arrow-functions performance in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

Are there any pros and cons for using the methods below to call a function in `react`? Or are they the same?

**Method 1**

```js
const ComponentA = () => {

  const handleClick = (something) => {
    console.log(something)
  }
  
  return <div onClick={() => handleClick("Hello world")} />
}
```

**Method 2**

```js
const ComponentA = () => {

  const handleClick = (something) => {
    console.log(something)
  }
  
  return <div onClick={handleClick.bind(this, "Hello world")} />
}
```

Comment: No real difference

Comment: Just on the first one, the function is created on every render. If that function does not uses any component variables (state, etc.); it is better to extract it out from the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin I’ll give a quick definition of what this is in React. this in general refers to a JavaScript element depending on the scope or context of its use. So in React, when we define classes we use methods inside those classes to refer to attributes such as state and props. For our methods to have access to this.state and this.props we need to bind the React component this context to those methods. Binding this to the class methods enables us to access props and state for the component with this.props and this.state. A benefit of using arrow functions is that this is already bound to that function so we don’t need to specify that anywhere else.

Both the methods are correct, the only difference is that the lines of code reduces if you use arrow function syntax rather than old function syntax